# Why does scheduling Spark jobs through cron fail (while the same command works when executed on terminal)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cron

I am trying to schedule a spark job using cron.
I have made a shell script and it executes well on the terminal.

However, when I execute the script using cron it gives me insufficient memory to start JVM thread error.

Every time I start the script using terminal there is no issue. This issue comes when the script starts with cron.
Kindly if you could suggest something.

Comment: What user does cron run as? Can you share the crontab entry? Do you have anything in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or any other shell init script to set `JAVA_OPTS` or similar? Compare `env` for cron user and yours.